# Angularjs directive DOM doesnt update

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm trying to update data in scope that is printed in DOM. The HTML is created by directive. But it doesn't updated

HTML code

```
<div ng-controller="triggerController">
   <the-click data-values="{{t_text}}"></the-click>
</div>
```

Javascript code

```
angular.controller('triggerController',
['$scope',function($scope){

        $scope.t_text   = 'I am original';

        $scope.clickme  = function(){
            $scope.t_text   = 'I have been clicked';
        }

    }
]).directive('theClick', function(){
return {
    scope: true,
    restrict:'E',
    link: function(scope, elm, attr){
        scope.sample = attr.values;

        elm.bind('click', function(e){
            scope.clickme(elm);
        })
    },
    controller:'triggerController',
    template: '<h1>{{sample}}</h1>'
}})
```

But the html does not update when i click. Why?

Comment: You are not observing the attribute. it's getting parsed to string while passing as a attribute. See answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    attr.$observe('values',function(){
      scope.sample = attr.values;
    });
```

Try this as you have to observe the attribute changes.

Comment: Thanks.. It works for me thought i dont know how $observe works. i will find it

Comment: I also added $scope.$apply() inside clickme()

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your script such as this:

```js
angular.module('testapp', [])
  .controller('triggerController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.t_text = 'I am original';
      $scope.clickme = function() {
        $scope.t_text = 'I have been clicked';
      }
    }
  ]).directive('theClick', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope:true,
      template: '<h1 ng-click="clickme()">{{t_text}}</h1>'
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='testapp' ng-controller="triggerController">
  <the-click data-values="{{t_text}}"></the-click>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're updating the $scope value inside the clickme method, which is called in a callback. Angular then has no way of knowing your data model has been updated. You must use $scope.$apply() to force angular to refresh your view

```
$scope.clickme  = function(){
     $scope.t_text   = 'I have been clicked';
     $scope.$apply();
};
```